# Python - Too Many Instance Variables? Design Convention?

Tags: python, oop

Good day, I have a very large class related to parsing files and assigning instance attributes. Now there are quite a bit of attributes that are tied to this class, however it seems cumbersome and would like some guidance. Here is my class:

```
class Node(object):
    """Node class is used to hold node object data."""

    DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR = 'Data Unavailable'

    def __init__(self, bundle, bundle_properties, file_map):
        self._bundle_location = bundle
        self._os_version = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._kernel_version = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._gdb_arg = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._docker_version = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._system_uptime = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._name = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._cpld_version = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._id = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._type = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._bios_vendor = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._bios_revision = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._bios_version = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._bios_release_date = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._system_serial_number = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._baseboard_version = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._baseboard_serial_number = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._chassis_version = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._chassis_serial_number = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._me_version = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._bmc_firmware_revision = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._bmc_ipmi_version = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._cpu_nums = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._cpu_model = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._cpu_cores = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._cpu_threads = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._cpu_cores_enabled = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._idrac_version = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._memory_gb = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._memory_mhz = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._network_driver = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._drive_nums = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._root_drive = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._nvram_num = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._nvram_vendor = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._nvram_ids = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._chassis_type = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._production_chassis_name = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._fibre_channel_model = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._fibre_channel_firmware_revision = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._management_ip = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._storage_ip = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._roles = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._rtfi_time = DATA_UNAVAILABLE_STR
        self._crash_count = 0
        self._esx_crash_count = 0
        self._healthy_status = True
        self._uncorrectable_ecc_dict_list = list()
        self._crash_obj_list = list()
        self._esx_crash_obj_list = list()
        self._dimm_info_list = list()
        self._drive_dict = dict()
```

Now I have methods in this class that parses files and does in fact populate all of these instance attributes but as you can tell, it's quite lengthy. Additionally, I have getters for all these attributes as well that return the protected instance attribute. What is the convention for long lists of instance variables that will be populated and referenced? Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: There's a lot of similar looking attributes (`_cpu_*`, `_bios_*`, `_nvram_*`, . . .). Breaking this up into smaller classes and then either inheriting or composing them may help. That depends on what each part of the class is doing though.

Comment: Python doesn't require that you declare variables before you use them, so you don't need to "pre-assign" what are essentially null values to all these variables in `__init__()`, especially since they are all private variables (beginning with `_`).

Comment: So I know python doesn't require it, however is that convention? Essentially I would be creating the instance variables on the fly without the representation for other people to see what is all in this class.

Comment: I could also be worth looking into dataclasses and thinking about using properties instead of getters and setters.

Comment: so I am actually using properties to retrieve the instance variables via Flask and a front-end design.

Comment: Reducing complexity and improving readability is definitely a good idea. I think this is implicitly a convention, somehow. It's hard to say what is the best design for that, e.g. using a huge container as input, using more inheritance or simply creating attributes on the fly when you need them. I think everything is possible and depends on your usecase.

Comment: "Additionally, I have getters for all these attributes as well that return the protected instance attribute" don't do that. Python != Java. There is no such thing as *protected*

Comment: On any case, this isn't an issue of what you should do in *python*, a class like this is code smell in any language. You need to rethink your abstractions

Comment: @colidyre data classes are just sugar. And I see no use case for `property` here. Fundamentally, the issue here is the overall design. Dressing that up in different language constructs doesn't address the fundamental issue here

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, I agree. I only said that this could be worth looking at it. I could have been clearer declaring this statement more as a side information, though.

Comment: You should think if you want to edit lots of code when things in that huge list change in the future. Actually you should even think if want to type all those attributes all the time in your present code. Splitting into several classes does not solve the problem in this respect.